# Adding a hue to a countplot in sns messes things up

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, hue

I am trying to plot a countplot of a specific column in sns.

This is the original code and plot:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns 

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.countplot(y=hosp_sat["HOSPITAL"], palette='Blues_r', order = hosp_sat['HOSPITAL'].value_counts().index);
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]);
ax;
```

and this is the plot it gives:

[image]

But then I try to add a hue based on the hospital size and this happens :

[image]

This is the code for it:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.countplot(y=hosp_sat["HOSPITAL"], hue=hosp_sat['Hospital_size'], order = hosp_sat['HOSPITAL'].value_counts().index);
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]);
ax;
```

it messes not only the alignment of the bars on the y axis, but also the labels .. How should I approach this?

P.S : the way that the dataframe looks like is this:

patient_id | hospital | size

1             Wolfson    big

2             Shiba      medium

3             Wolfson    big

maybe that the hospital and it's size appear more than once affect that ?

##UPDATE## : after I adjusted the code with the help of the answers, we can fix the labels using this :

```
for label in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(label);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `dodge=False`.

[Docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

> dodge : bool, optional
>
> When hue nesting is used, whether elements should be shifted along the categorical axis.

Comment: Thanks !! it worked . what about the labels though ? it's like in the second pic

Comment: Now that I checked again, the labels are only for the bars with a blue hue "big hospitals", what could trigger that?